# In DBT is there a clean way to tie off a for loop?

Tags: dbt

Consider this macro that I wrote:

```
{% macro concatenate_columns() %}

    {% for column in [col_1, col_2, col_3] %}

    "{{column}}" ||

    {% endfor %}
    ''

{% endmacro %}
```

The point of the macro is to take an array of columns and concatenate them together. However, the after the `{% endfor %}` I have to include a `''` in order to prevent the macro returning the final characters as `||`.

This is a common problem I have faced with for loops. Here's it's not syntactically hard to deal with, but I've had a situation where I used `UNION`s between loops, and the added bit at the end became very complex.

Is there a clean way to write for loops where the final loop "ties off" the output, and doesn't continue to append?

Comment: You can accomplish the same result with `join` without using a for loop. `{{ '\'' ~ [col_1, col_2, col_3] | join('\' || \'') ~ '\'' }}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Jinja you would use the `{% if [not] loop.last %}` bit, to let the program know that whenever you are dealing with the last iteration in the loop (or all the iterations but the last one, hence the `[not]` in there), you want a different behaviour.

For instance, in your example you could use the following:

```
{% macro concatenate_columns() %}

    {% for column in [col_1, col_2, col_3] %}

      "{{column}}" {% if not loop.last %} || ' ' || {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Which should compile as:
`col_1  || ' ' || col_2 || ' ' || col_3`

This way, as long as you are *not* in the last iteration of your `for` loop, you will add a concat (`||`) + space (`' '`) + concat (`||`) in your code.

Comment: Fantastic answer, exactly what I was looking for. I just tested it an works exactly as expected. Thanks!